# Output Form Field Values in React

Tags: javascript, json, forms, reactjs, output

I am currently developing my first React App and I am trying to make a simple form which will output values into a format which can be stored for later use (possibly a JSON file).

I have tried outputting the values to an alert rather than going straight to a JSON file but even in this I have had no success.

Basically what I want is to take the values from the form in the state that they are in when the submit button is pushed and output them into a usable format.

A Snippet of the code that I am using is below.

```
class PeripheralPage extends React.Component {
    state = {
    peripherals: [
      {
        name: "Product 1",
        installation: 79.99,
        monthly: 5.99,
        count: 1,
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        perimage: peripheralimage
      },
      {
        name: "Product 2",
        installation: 19.99,
        monthly: 9.99,
        count: 2,
        min: 2,
        max: 12,
        perimage: peripheralimage
      },
      {
        name: "Product 3",
        installation: 19.99,
        monthly: 9.99,
        count: 4,
        min: 3,
        max: 8,
        perimage: peripheralimage
      }
    ]
  };

  onChange = (index, val) => {
    this.setState({
      peripherals: this.state.peripherals.map(
        (name, i) => (i === index ? { ...name, count: val } : name)
      )
    });
  };


  submitPackage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var periphs = {PeripheralList}
    var installationCost = {InstallTotal}
    alert('Your Package includes: ' + PeripheralList + installationCost );
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.submitPackage.bind(this)}>
        <PeripheralList
          peripherals={this.state.peripherals}
          onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
        />
        <InstallTotal ref="installCost" peripherals={this.state.peripherals} />
        <MonthlyTotal peripherals={this.state.peripherals} />
        <input type="submit" value="Save Package" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const PeripheralList = ({ peripherals, onChange }) =>
  <div>
    {peripherals.map((peripherals, i) =>
      <div key={i}>
        <div className="componentname">{peripherals.name}</div>
        <div className="installcost">Install: £{peripherals.installation}</div>
        <div className="monthlycost">Monthly: £{peripherals.monthly}</div>
        <div className="quantity">
        <input
          type="number"
          min={peripherals.min} 
          max={peripherals.max}
          value={peripherals.count}
          onChange={e => onChange(i, parseInt(e.target.value, 10)|| 0)}
        />
        </div>

      </div>
    )}
  </div>;

const InstallTotal = ({ peripherals }) =>
  <h3>
    Installation Cost:
    £{peripherals.reduce((sum, i) => (sum += i.count * i.installation), 0)}
  </h3>;

const MonthlyTotal = ({ peripherals }) =>
  <h3>
    Monthly Cost:
    £{peripherals.reduce((sum, i) => (sum += i.count * i.monthly), 0)}
  </h3>;
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated with this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, it was simpler than I was making, it my new code is below

```
import productdata from "./myjsonfile.json";

class productTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <span>
                  {productdata.data.productgroup[0].name} 
                </span>
                <span>
                  {productdata.data.productgroup[0].description}
                </span>
                <span>
                  Price: £{
                    productdata.data.productgroup[0].price
                  }
                </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                <span>
                  {productdata.data.productgroup[1].name} 
                </span>
                <span>
                  {productdata.data.productgroup[1].description}
                </span>
                <span>
                  Price: £{
                    productdata.data.productgroup[1].price
                  }
                </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that "data" and "productgroup" are values within the json file itself, the number in square brackets is the product group that the values appear in

Answer (score 0):

Your input `input` needs to have `name` like so:

```
<input
          onChange={this.onFormInputChange}
          name ='number_name'
          type="number"
          min={peripherals.min} 
          max={peripherals.max} />
```

And your onChange should be like so:

```
onFormInputChange(event) {
        let form = this.state.form;
        form[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ form });
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer but I'm afraid that I don't quite understand. 

The "number" input in the PeripheralList component already has an onChange which is used to generate a total at the bottom of the form and I'm usure where the onFormInputChange would go as it brings up an error when I try to input it.

Also how would I out the values of the form once the Submit button has been pressed. 

I apologise if I'm being slow here but I'm just a little confused.

Comment: When you change the values in your form, is your state updating accordingly ?

Comment: I believe so. The totals at the bottom are updating when I enter a new number in the input. The problem is that I'm unsure how to get the values shown in the form (once the desired inputs have been entered) to output into a unique JSON file where I can use them in another area of the app.

Comment: Yes it appears to be